# ios 8 swift - how to add footer for tableview using separate datasource

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, uitableview

For 2 days I'm trying to solve this.
I just want to add a footer (custom cell) to my tableview.
I have a view with some stuff on it (labels, buttons) and I've added a tableview.
To have a clean controller, for the datasource I'm using a separate file:

```
class MyDataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
 ...   
}
```

In my controller I have :

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!
    var myDatasource: MyDataSource!
    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myDatasource = MyDataSource(....)
        myTableView.dataSource = myDatasource
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
```

So, in `MyDataSource` I've added:

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let footerView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 40))
        footerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        return footerView
    }

     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 40.0
    }
```

And this piece of code is not being called.
I've looked the documentation and I've found that these 2 last methods are part of `UITableViewController` and not of part of `UITableViewDataSource`.

So, my question is, how to achieve that ?

Thanks.

C.C.

Comment: its a delegate method...had you set the tableview delegate with the viewcontroller

Comment: tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) is part of UITableViewDelegate protocol and You have to set the tableview delegate as myDatasource. In your code you had not given the myTableView.delegate = myDatasource

Comment: Yes, it was so stupid. I just saw, I did't put the delegate for my tableview. Now it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted, displaying headers and footers needs to implement the relevant method of the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol. For the footer it is:

```
tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int)
```

Make sure your table view's delegate is set correctly.

Also, note that there is another convenient table view feature: a footer that will be added below the entire table view, regardless of datasource or delegate implementation. Just assign a `tableFooterView`.

Answer (score 4):

Swift 3 (note underscores):

```
override func tableView( _ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? 

override func tableView( _ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat
```